# How do I update Safari on the Macintosh?

Tags: safari

How do I upgrade Safari on the Mac?

Is there one web page to always get the current version?
Or are there instructions somewhere for how to manually update Safari (assuming auto update is not enabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you would go to the apple menu and click Software Update.  This will launch the App Store and search for updates for all your software.  If there is new software out there, it will show up.

Or, alternatively, you can go here: http://www.apple.com/support/safari/ and click the update link.

dp